# Tear off tabs in GVIM just like chrome or firefox

Tags: vim, tabs, gvim, window, gui

Is there a way to move tabs to a different instance of GVIM? I'm looking for something similar to how most web browsers function. When you drag a tab out of its current window, it either creates a new window or drops it into an existing window. Please note, when I say window I don't mean the vim definition of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Vim does not support multiple "toplevel" windows within the same process, no, Vim doesn't support anything like this.

You could potentially create a user-defined function and command or mapping that would let you do it, but it would have to first close the file in the current Vim session then create a new Vim process to open the file.